# ASP.NET Setting Visible = false doesn't stay

Tags: asp.net, webforms, click, visible

I have a lot of buttons that I want to appear when I tell them to and so far I have been using Visible = true or false depending on when I want them to appear or not.  I want the button to disappear after the click event has occurred on it.  I have two buttons in the code and when I click on btnOption131 it disappears but than when I click on btnOption132 it disappears and btnOption131 re-appears.  Is there anyway I can stop this from happening?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOption131" runat="server" Text="Think" OnClick="btnOption131_Click" Visible="False" CssClass="button"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnOption132" runat="server" Text="Go Crazy" OnClick="btnOption132_Click" Visible="False"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void btnOption131_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt1.Text = statementArray1[8].ToString();
    btnOption131.EnableViewState = false;
    btnOption131.Visible = false;
}

protected void btnOption132_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt1.Text = statementArray1[9].ToString();
    btnOption132.EnableViewState = false;
    btnOption132.Visible = false;
}
```

I also tried:

```
    protected void btnOption131_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt1.Text = statementArray1[8].ToString();
    btnOption131.Visible = false;
}

protected void btnOption132_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txt1.Text = statementArray1[9].ToString();
    btnOption132.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the button `Visibility` to 'true' somewhere. My guess is that it is not wrapped inside an `IsPostBack` check:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        btnOption131.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

If you do not do this the visibility will always be set to `true` when the next PostBack (= button click) occurs.

Comment: Sorry I should have stated I tried with and without    btnOption131.EnableViewState = false;

Comment: Can you post the code where you are setting the button visibility to `true`. Because I can only get the same results if I remove the `IsPostBack` check.

Comment: I have this and still doesn't work correctly some don't show up it does get rid of them after click event has occurred though. `protected void btnOption121_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { txt1.Text = statementArray1[6].ToString(); btnOption121.Visible = false; if (IsPostBack == false) { btnOption131.Visible = true; } }`